# PySpark replace column value with another column value on multiple conditions

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I am trying to replace col1 values in case it equals Null and col2 equals to col3 in each row. If this is true, then col1 value should be repalced with col4 value in every row of the dataframe.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when

df = df.withColumn("col1", when((df.col1 == None) & (df.col2 == df.col3), df.col4))
```

Comment: what's the problem with your approach?

Comment: All the values become Null for some reason in col1.

Comment: check for nulls using `df.col1.isNull()`, and use `otherwise()` at the end so that non-matching records will get retained

Comment: maybe you have to use lit(None)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if null/None in pySpark we usually use `isnull()` , also we need to use `.otherwise( df.col1 )` so it become as ,

```
df = df.withColumn("col1", when( isnull(df.col1) & (df.col2 == df.col3), df.col4)).otherwise( df.col1 )
```

If need to go in details why `.otherwise( df.col1 )` ?

what `.withColumn()` desribed to do ?

`Returns a new DataFrame by adding a column or replacing the existing column that has the same name` ,

So we can only create a new column as whole and either add it to df `or` replace already existing one , in our case it create a new dataframe with `replacing existing column` with the one we have created with same name.

we want to create it as we need in `replace ... in case` which means if a certain condition specified we replace it ( or in other words set other column value instead this column ) okay until here it works well but what if the condition not satisfied what value to set , in code it's not specified at all and unfortunately by default it's set to `Null` ( i.e doesn't look at original column value as it's expected in your code to happen ) so this results that all rows where condition not satisfied `col1` value will be `Null`.

we solve this by specify what if the `when condition` not satisfied , to set the value to our target original column , using `.otherwise()` and pass the `df.col1` value so once not satisfied it will set the `df.col1` value , which actually the original value ( seems like not replaced at all ! ) and that's it .

Hope it Helps !